# Call procedure (long name) into variable (not free)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg, icebreak

I'm trying to call a procedure and assign a variable with the output.

My problem is that my procedure name is to long for the allowed space:

This is my working source, is it posible to use `move` or `movel` and do the same?

```
c                   eval      pSitProp      = json_parseString(wSitProp)
```

...

```
  3774 c                   move      pSitProp      json_parseString(wSitProp)                            01 CA050            005000                                                                  
======>                                                          aaaaabbccddee                                                      
*RNF5038 20 a      005000  Field-Length entry is not valid; defaults to blanks.                                                     
*RNF5044 20 b      005000  Decimal-Positions entry is not blank or 0 - 63; defaults to                                              
                           0.                                                                                                       
*RNF5051 20 c      005000  Resulting-Indicator entry is not valid; defaults to blanks.                                              
*RNF5051 20 d      005000  Resulting-Indicator entry is not valid; defaults to blanks.                                              
*RNF5051 20 e      005000  Resulting-Indicator entry is not valid; defaults to blanks.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can not use `MOVE` or `MOVEL`

You've got a lot of extra space between the results variable and the procedure call that is not needed.  Your code actually fits just fine in a single line.

```
 c                   eval      pSitProp = json_parseString(wSitProp)
```

But let's pretend it doesn't.
You need to read up on the RPGLE [continuation rules](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzasd/sc092508340.htm%23cont)

Here's one way to break the line.

```
 c                   eval      pSitProp
 c                              = json_parseString(wSitProp)
```

If need be you can break up long names using the ellipsis (...) like so:

```
 c                   eval      pSitProp = json_parseString(wSit...
 c                              Prop)
```

Having said that, the best choice is to simply use free format.

```
    pSitProp = json_parseString(wSitProp);
```

Comment: Yea i know about free format.. I'm simply trying to experience a little with fixed format.. Comming from a frontEnd background to rpg is kind of fun.

Comment: Welcome.  In that case, I can understand wanting to play with fixed format.  But in all honestly, RPG IV is really designed for free format.  The support of fixed format at this point is simply to allow you to CVTRPGSRC from RPG III to RPG IV.  Just be sure you stay away from obsolete op-codes such as move.

Comment: Charles is right. Older op-codes such as `MOVE` had real function in an earlier era. Today they should not be mixed with newer functionality such as procedure calls and variable length items. The old technical elements that used to exist are no longer needed and can cause problems.